# Spinning up a Dataproc cluster with Spark BigQuery Connector

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

Reading the instructions under this repo: [Google Cloud Storage and BigQuery connectors](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/connectors)
I followed the below initialization action to create a new Dataproc cluster with a specific version of Google Cloud Storage and BigQuery connector installed:

```
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create christos-test \
--region europe-west1 \
--subnet <a subnet zone> \
--optional-components=ANACONDA,JUPYTER \
--enable-component-gateway \
--initialization-actions gs://<bucket-name>/init-scripts/v.0.0.1/connectors.sh \
--metadata gcs-connector-version=1.9.16 \
--metadata bigquery-connector-version=0.13.16 \
--zone europe-west1-b \
--master-machine-type n1-standard-4 \
--worker-boot-disk-size 500 \
--image=<an-image> \
--project=<a-project-id> \
--service-account=composer-dev@vf-eng-ca-nonlive.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--no-address \
--max-age=5h \
--max-idle=1h \
--labels=<owner>=christos,<team>=group \
--tags=allow-internal-dataproc-dev,allow-ssh-from-management-zone,allow-ssh-from-management-zone2 \
```

--properties=core:fs.gs.implicit.dir.repair.enable=false

As you should be able to see, I had to add the external dependencies in a bucket of my own under: `gs://init-dependencies-big-20824/init-scripts/v.0.0.1/connectors.sh`. As per the scipt's instructions (I am referring to the `connector.sh` script), I also had to add the following jars in this bucket:

- gcs-connector-hadoop2-1.9.16.jar
- gcs-connector-1.7.0-hadoop2.jar
- gcs-connector-1.8.0-hadoop2.jar
- bigquery-connector-hadoop2-0.13.16.jar

The script works fine and the cluster is created successfully. However, using a `PySpark` notebook through `Jupyter` still results in a `BigQuery` "class not found" exception. The same happens when I run `PySpark` directly from the terminal. The only way I was able to avoid that exception is by copying another `jar` (this time `spark-bigquery_2.11-0.8.1-beta-shaded.jar`) in my cluster's master node and starting `PySpark` with:

```
pyspark --jars spark-bigquery_2.11-0.8.1-beta-shaded.jar
```

Obviously, this beats the purpose.

What am I doing wrong? I thought about changing the `connector.sh` script to include another `copy` function so copy `spark-bigquery_2.11-0.8.1-beta-shaded.jar` under `/usr/lib/hadoop/lib`, so I tried to just copy this `jar` there manually and start `PySpark` but this still didn't work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connectors init action applies only to [Cloud Storage](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.google.cloud.bigdataoss%20AND%20a:gcs-connector%20AND%20v:hadoop2-*) and [BigQuery](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.google.cloud.bigdataoss%20AND%20a:bigquery-connector%20AND%20v:hadoop2-*) connectors for Hadoop from [GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors).

Generally you should not use BigQuery connector for Hadoop if you are using Spark, because there are newer [BigQuery connector](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.google.cloud.spark%20AND%20a:spark-bigquery_2.11&core=gav) for Spark in the [spark-bigquery-connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-bigquery-connector) repository that you already adding with `--jars` parameter.

To install Spark BigQuery connector during cluster creation you will need to write your own initialization action that copies it in the `/usr/lib/spark/jars/` directory on the cluster nodes. Note that you don't need to replicate all the code in the connectors init action, but just copy Spark BigQuery connector shaded jar from you Cloud Storage bucket to the `/usr/lib/spark/jars/` directory:

```sh
gsutil cp gs://path/to/spark-bigquery-connector.jar /usr/lib/spark/jars/
```

Better approach could be to embed Spark BigQuery connector in your application distribution with other dependencies.

#### Update

[Connectors initialization action](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/initialization-actions/tree/master/connectors) now supports Spark BigQuery connector, and can be used to install Spark BigQuery connector on Dataproc cluster during cluster creation:

```sh
REGION=<region>
CLUSTER_NAME=<cluster_name>
gcloud dataproc clusters create ${CLUSTER_NAME} \
    --region ${REGION} \
    --initialization-actions gs://goog-dataproc-initialization-actions-${REGION}/connectors/connectors.sh \
    --metadata spark-bigquery-connector-version=0.15.1-beta
```

Comment: This is a sensible response however I still can't get `pyspark` to work properly even after copying the relevant jar under the path you provided... Trying to run a read still results in `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.direct.BigQueryPartition`.

Comment: Interesting, I have tested it with the `gsutil cp gs://maven-central/repos/central/data/com/google/cloud/spark/spark-bigquery_2.11/0.8.1-beta/spark-bigquery_2.11-0.8.1-beta-shaded.jar /usr/lib/spark/jars/` init action and `spark.read.format("bigquery").option("table", "publicdata.samples.shakespeare").load().show()` PySpark program and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use Google public spark-lib that includes dependencies

```
--jars "gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar
```

or

```
--jars "gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest.jar
```

depending upon the Scala version that Dataproc cluster is deployed with

It works beautifully for me.

Comment: This works for jobs, but not cluster creation. This specific question seems to ask about cluster creation.